# Is there a way to pass neither serializable nor Parcelable objects to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am building an app that connects to a SSE service. I am thinking of a splash screen which is displayed until the connection is done. My problem is, how do I pass the SSE client object to the activity?

Comment: use one activity, different fragments, save whatever you want on the common activity

Comment: Neither the Activity (or Fragments) should really know (or care) about your SSE Client Object. The object that contains that SSE Client Object (let's call it "the object") should either be provided by a Dependency Injection mechanism, Service Locator, or similar pattern. As such, when an activity finishes to move to another, all they need to do is ask for this "Object". Analogy: Don't carry the whole phonebook with you, simply save the "page number" where the data you want is, and whenever you need it, ask for the page to a PhoneBook :)